# importing a contract does not access to its modifiers

Tags: solidity, contract-development

Contract A imports Contract B and Contract B contains a modifier that I want to use in contract A. Contract A is set to inherit from Contract B, however I get the following when I try to use the modifier in Contract A:

```
Error: solc: exit status 1
<stdin>:1:1: Error: Declaration "modifierInB" not found in "B" (referenced as "./B").
import {modifierInB} from "./B";
^--------------------------------^
```

I have tried this with the below with similar results

```
import "./B";
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong or can I simply not move a Contract containing a modifier to another file?

Comment: You found an answer for this ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to import the modifier, just import B, and make A inherit from it.
Then on A, you can define a function that uses the modifierInB.

Take a look here:
https://github.com/elopio/solidity-experiments/tree/master/contracts/ContractWithInheritedModifier